# Expand excel column using delphi

Tags: delphi, excel, export, expand

If I have a DBGrid in a form filled with some data and I want to export the the grid to a excel file how can I expand the columns in the excel file depending on the content of the columns.

Comment: Do you have a working code without expanding the columns widths?

Comment: You are using OLE automation to control Excel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [`Range.AutoFit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.autofit%28v=office.11%29.aspx) method.